# How to avoid posting duplicate sales receipt in Quickbooks desktop version using Data service?

Tags: quickbooks

I am posting Sales Rceipts from my application to QuickBooks Desktop using Data Service. My Invoice numbers are unique and i am posting them as a SalesReceipt DocNumner. I just wanted to check if the same DocNumber is already present in QuickBooks wittout querying all the QB Sales Receipts.
Is there any way to do it?
-Bharat

Answer (score 0):

'DocNumber' is not an unique key and it is not mentioned in the following docs as a filter attribute. So, you have to query all the QB SalesReceipts.

```
for (QBSalesReceipt salesReceipt : qbSalesReceipt.findAll(context,i, 100)) {
    System.out.println("Doc Number - " + salesReceipt.getHeader().getDocNumber());
}
```

IPP Docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/salesreceipt#Retrieving_SalesReceipts_Using_a_Query_Filter